# Generate Alphanumeric for document ID ,error at max()

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is the method created to auto generate Alphanumeric DocNo.
but since the value is empty,the Max() method throws an error

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
> Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Method

```
private void increment()
    { 

        using (dbLinQBI1DataContext dbLE = new dbLinQBI1DataContext())
        {
            var a = (from s in dbLE.TransactionDetails select s.DocNo).Max();
            int Num1 = Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(3, 1));
            string str = a.Substring(0, 3);
            int n = Num1 + 1;
            str = str.Substring(0, 3) + n;
            txtDN.Text = str;
        
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: add your error to your post also add an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use null conditional operator like below

```
var a = (from s in dbLE.TransactionDetails select s.DocNo)?.Max();
```

Before accessing the variable `a`, you have to check for `null`. I hope `DocNo` is `varchar` column in your database.

One more thing, I wrote answer for solving null issue. If you want to get max value in  alpha numeric column, you should do it in SQL itself not in C#.